# New Line output CloudFormation Json Template

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

This is my Output section for JSON script that I use for CloudFormation template.

```
"Outputs": {


"Value":{"Fn::Join": [" ",["Username : ",{"Ref": "Username"},"Password : ",{"Ref":     "Pass"}]]},

}
```

How do I print Output in below format:

username : abc 
password : abc

Right now I am getting this in same line (Username: abc Password abc).

Answer (score 0):

Try appending new line. It should work. As the arguments are taken as string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not print these out as separate outputs?

```
  "Outputs" : {
    "Username" : {
      "Description" : "Username",
      "Value": { "Ref": "Username" }
    },
    "Password" : {
      "Description" : "Password",
      "Value": { "Ref": "Password" }
    }
  }
```